# Installing Git Server on Windows server 2012 for a dev. team. Is SSH server mandatory?

Tags: ssh, windows-server-2012, installation, git

I want to install git server on a Windows Server 2012 for my development team. 
In some tutorials, I read that a SSH Server is needed. Is it mandatory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Other transport protocols are available, like `http` or `git`.

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols